# Invoke Python API from PHP

Tags: php, python

how i can reproduce the same thing in PHP:

```
import xmlrpclib
s = xmlrpclib.Server("http://domainname.com/Verify.py", verbose = False)
print s.verify({"var1" : "test","var2" : "A" })
print s.verify({"var1" : "test","var2" : "H" })
```

Answer (score 0):

XML-RPC is nice because it's language agnostic. As long as XML-RPC libraries are provided by a language, we can use that language. Assume A is your local machine and B is the server. In your example, both A (client) and B are running Python.

The official PHP api for XML-RPC can be found on the php site. However, i it's pretty bare since there's no documentation. I recommend grabbing the code from this repo: https://github.com/gggeek/phpxmlrpc/ which has much better [documentation](http://gggeek.github.io/phpxmlrpc/). So, to answer your question, we just need to two things:

1. Set up client to query the server
2. Call server to get result

Converting your code sample to PHP would then look something like:

```
$client = new xmlrpc_client("/Verify.py", "http://domainname.com", 80);
$message = new xmlrpcmsg("verify",
                  array(new xmlrpcval(test, "string")));
$response = $client->send($message);
$result = $response->value
```

Just for fun, let's reverse things... Now assume that you want to call a PHP function on the XML-RPC server using Python. In other words, A is running Python and B is running PHP.

```
import xmlrpclib

# Create an object to represent server.
server = xmlrpclib.Server("http://domainname.com/functions.php");

# Call the server to get result.
result = server.functions.multiplyAndDivide(20, 4)
print "Product:", result['product']
print "Quotient:", result['quotient']
```

Comment: thanks soo much for the detailed reply, i don't understand how to pass the variable name and the second parameter.

Comment: give me this error: Connect error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)

Comment: sounds like there is an issue with the URI you're specifying. I don't know what that is since I was using the example host name and function you provided. Try playing with that and making small changes to see if you can hit the server and the correct function. Here's a helpful link on creating the client: http://gggeek.github.io/phpxmlrpc/doc-1.1/ch05s01.html#d0e322

Comment: As for sending the request, check this doc out for how to create the message that will call the function and add parameters: http://gggeek.github.io/phpxmlrpc/doc-1.1/ch05s02.html